# How can I add a role to default roles in keycloak using admin-cli

Tags: keycloak

I am using admin-cli to add some pre-configurations to a keycloak 3.4.3 docker container.

One of the things that i want to do is add a certain realm role to the list of Default Realm Roles, so that this role is applied automatically when a new user is registered (using the web user registration form).

I couldn’t find anything about this in the documentation.
Any ideas on how this could be achieved using admin-cli commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same question today. Here is my solution:

```
echo Creating realm TEST
kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=test -s enabled=true

echo Creating Test_Default role
kcadm.sh create roles -r test -s name=test_default

echo Adding Test_Default role to the TEST realm default roles
kcadm.sh update realms/test -f - << EOF
{ "realm": "test", "enabled": true, "defaultRoles" : [ "offline_access", "uma_authorization", "test_default" ] }
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Keycloak 18.0.0 changing the Realm Default Roles using `kcadm.sh` doesn't work via updating the realm's JSON, but does via composite rules.

When we create a realm (e.g. named `realm-test1`), Keycloak automatically creates a corresponding composite rule `default-roles-realm-test1` and populates it with built-in roles `offline_access` and `uma_authorization`:

[image: Fresh realm before running script]

Here is how we add our own role to (and remove a role from) Realm Default Roles.

```bash
$ docker exec -ti keycloak_keycloak_1 bash
bash-4.4$ /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=realm-test1 -s enabled=true
Created new realm with id 'realm-test1'

bash-4.4$ /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create roles -r realm-test1 -s name=role-test1
Created new role with id 'role-test1'

bash-4.4$ /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh add-roles --rname default-roles-realm-test1 --rolename role-test1 -r realm-test1

bash-4.4$ /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh remove-roles --rname default-roles-realm-test1 --rolename offline_access -r realm-test1
```

Hitting F5 in the browser we see that it works:

[image: Realm after running script]

**Documentation**

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#adding-realm-roles-to-a-composite-role